# Music Shop Table

Tags: sql

I created a database in InterBase with the provisional name "Musical
shop", consisting of the following interconnected tables:

1. **Artists**

   | Field assignment | Field Name | Type | Size |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | Identifier | ID | INT |  |
   | Artist name | Artist | VARCHAR | 80 |
2. **Albums**

   | Field assignment | Field Name | Type | Size |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | Identifier | ID | INT |  |
   | Album Title | Album | VARCHAR | 100 |
   | A pointer to the artist | Artist | INT |  |
3. **Genres**

   | Field assignment | Field Name | Type | Size |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | Identifier | ID | INT |  |
   | Genre name | Genre | VARCHAR | 80 |
4. **Songs**

   | Field assignment | Field Name | Type | Size |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | Identifier | ID | INT |  |
   | Track number in album | Track | INT |  |
   | Track title | Name | VARCHAR | 160 |
   | A pointer to the album | Album | INT |  |
   | Genre (pointer) | Genre | INT |  |

Respectively, I have the following SQL queries for creating respective tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Artists (
ID INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(80),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Albums (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Artist INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Genres (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(80),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Songs (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Track INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(160),
    Album INT NOT NULL,
    Genre INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

However, I need to complete the following tasks (create SQL queries):

1. Make a query that, by artist name, displays all non-duplicate track titles of this artist, sorted alphabetically
2. Make a query that, by genre name, displays all the names of artists who have at least one track in this genre, sorted alphabetically

Comment: I suggest you write queries yourself and share them here to solve the probable problem.

Comment: First learn the basics of SQL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_syntax then try something simple that works and then move forward to create the more complex queries. When your stuck, then come back with your problem. This is how SO works: it’s not a place where you can ask for things like ‘create my application using these specs’.

Comment: This has nothing to do with *Delphi* and is SQL generic enough to not be bound to *InterBase* either. You put good effort in your formatting, but please remove those two tags.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Is it home work that has been assigned to you? Better you search by yourself. There are a lot of SQL tutorials available on the internet. Once you get your first request but are face with an issue, then ask a specific question about that issue. Start with a pure SQL request in the tool that is delivered with your database. Then later you'll use that request inside a Delphi program (That is a different problem).